# The child entity is incompatible with the base entity [typescript]

Tags: typescript, types

I have added `"strict": true` in my `tsconfig.json` and started to get compiler errors. You can copy code to test this case. Why child class is incompatible with the base class? Maybe a solution exists or I'm doing something wrong?

```
export class AbstractDto {
    id: string;
    createdAt: Date;
    updatedAt: Date;

    constructor(entity: AbstractEntity) {
        this.id = entity.id;
        this.createdAt = entity.createdAt;
        this.updatedAt = entity.updatedAt;
    }
}

export abstract class AbstractEntity<T extends AbstractDto = AbstractDto> {
    id: string = '';
    createdAt: Date = new Date();
    updatedAt: Date = new Date();

    abstract dtoClass: new (entity: AbstractEntity, options?: any) => T;
}
export class UserEntity extends AbstractEntity<AbstractDto> {
    firstName: string = '';
    one: string = '';

    dtoClass = UserDto;
//  ^^^^^^^^ - Property 'dtoClass' in type 'UserEntity' 
//             is not assignable to the same property in base type 'AbstractEntity<AbstractDto>'.
}

export class UserDto extends AbstractDto {
    one: string = '';

    constructor(user: UserEntity) {
        super(user);
//            ^^^^ - Argument of type 'UserEntity' 
//                   is not assignable to parameter of type 'AbstractEntity<AbstractDto>'.
        this.one = user.one;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the errors you described. And after playing with your code, the modified version below seems to yield no errors. At least, on my computer.

```
export class AbstractDto {
    id: string;
    createdAt: Date;
    updatedAt: Date;

    constructor(entity: AbstractEntity) {
        this.id = entity.id;
        this.createdAt = entity.createdAt;
        this.updatedAt = entity.updatedAt;
    }
}

// Generic is not needed as we will use "typeof" keyword (see below).
// export abstract class AbstractEntity<T extends AbstractDto = AbstractDto> {
export abstract class AbstractEntity {
    id: string = '';
    createdAt: Date = new Date();
    updatedAt: Date = new Date();

    // abstract dtoClass: new (entity: AbstractEntity, options?: any) => T;
    abstract dtoClass: typeof AbstractDto; // Use "typeof" instead
}

// Remove generic here too because we removed generic from the "AbstractEntity" class above
// export class UserEntity extends AbstractEntity<AbstractDto> {
export class UserEntity extends AbstractEntity {
    firstName: string = '';
    one: string = '';

    dtoClass = UserDto;
}

export class UserDto extends AbstractDto {
    one: string = '';

    constructor(user: UserEntity) {
        super(user);
        this.one = user.one;
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your participation. In my case, I need base classes to encapsulate part of common properties and not concretize the basic class.

Comment: Is it possible with typescript strict type system? This validation controlled by `strictFunctionTypes` tsconfig property.

Comment: That's what I suspect. I removed the "strict" option and the errors vanished. I did review the docs on `strictFunctionTypes` but the example there is not similar to yours so it's hard to say. However, what I can say is that those errors really have something to do with the `strict` option.

Comment: Thank you, but not in this case. I have assigned default values to repair compiler errors before this problem.

Comment: I just updated the answer with new code. Can you give it a try?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this solution is possible in my case. Please edit your answer with a short explanation. For instance, you can describe removing generic from the AbstractEntity class and the difference of the abstract property typeof.

Comment: Glad that help!
I updated the code adding comments to where I made the changes.